# FirebaseMessagingService is not called on app start

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use FirebaseMessagingService to handle push notifications from the server. But there is not called `onCreate` function at the start. I thought that this service is initialized automatically when the app starts. Also, I started to send testing notification from firebase cloud messaging but it didn't work.

```
    class PushNotificationService: FirebaseMessagingService() {
    private lateinit var app: App

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        App.log("FireBaseMsg: starting service")
        app = application as App
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(msg: RemoteMessage?) {
        super.onMessageReceived(msg)

        App.log("FireBaseMsg: onMessageReceived")
        val pNotification = msg?.notification
        if (pNotification != null){
            val title = pNotification.title
            val text = pNotification.body

            if (!title.isNullOrEmpty() && !text.isNullOrEmpty()){
                val p = PushNotification(app, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_PUSH, title = title, text = text)
                p.fireNotification(NOTIFICATION_ID_PUSH)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        App.log("FireBaseMsg: Received token: $token")
        //REGISTER TOKEN
        app.regPushNotification(token, ::onNewTokenCallback)
    }

    private fun onNewTokenCallback(err: ApiCallError?){
        if (err == null){
            app.showToast(app.getString(R.string.notification_push_token_failed))
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<service
   android:name=".services.PushNotificationService"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: FirebaseMessagingService is automatically get called. You will receive new token inside `onNewToken `

Comment: But onNewToken was not called at start

Comment: which version of library you are using?

Comment: Also, have you included `google-services.json` at the correct place under app package?

Comment: Yes, just solved it by reinstalling app for 5 times. Really annoyed by this new google caching system. My shared prefs and data were cached even after clearing cache and data manually and then uninstalling my app. Did this process 5 times in a row and at 6th time it finally cleared all of my cached data which eventually led to service oncreate call and everything is working.

Comment: Side note: You can add `android:allowBackup="false"` under Application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: it will remove the cache

Answer (score 6):

I was in same problem while i am implementing FirebaseMessagingService class

**My solution**

Manifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingServices"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

If everything ok in your manifest service section then

1. Uninistall your application
2. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart....
3. Run your application

Comment: Thank you soooo much for the last section about uninstalling, invalidating caches & restarting, then running the application! After hours upon hours of research, this was the only thing that worked for me to get the registration token to show in the logs via `onNewToken`.

I didn't need the additional things in the manifest, just the bare minimum declarations made in the official FirebaseMessagingService documentation/tutorial.

Comment: I had to add         android:enabled="true" and leave android:exported="false"